# link click works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have hidden div that contain a div inside it and this div is hidden by default , and i have link should bring the content of (#mobiles_thumbs) div , every thing work perfectly just for first click on the link and the second click the div that change its content disappear i used (on) delegate . this is my code :

```js
//and here my jquery code for handle the link click : 

$('#products').on('click', 'a', function() {

  $("#thumbs").html($("#thumbs_collection #mobiles_thumbs"));
  /* here #thumbs_collection is the name of big div that contain six 
  div inside it.
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- this is the hidden div -->
<div id="thumbs_collection">
  <div id="mobiles_thumbs" style="visibility:hidden">
    <img alt="mobile1" src="images/mobile1.jpg">
    <img alt="mobile2" src="images/mobile2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="products" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <h1>Our Products </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#mobiles"> Mobiles </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#swatches"> Swatches </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#chairs"> Chairs </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#boxs">Boxs </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#Doors"> Doors </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#windows"> Windows </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs">
      <!--this div for load the products -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add more code to show the actual issue? Do you have any console erors?

Comment: Well, what's supposed to happen the second time you click it? It looks like it only changes the HTML into something specific **once**, how would it be any different on subsequent clicks ?

Comment: no every thing is ok , but just when i clicked the link for first time it is worked , and clicked it again the div (#thumbs) is blank again

Comment: maybe user click the link many times , on the second click the (#thumbs) div content disappear

Comment: ok this is an example click the mobile link and the div will appear , click it another time and the div will disappear , why ? http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/7024/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cloning the element fist and don't forget to toggle visibility after the html append

```
var temp = $("#thumbs_collection #mobiles_thumbs").clone();
$('#products').on('click', 'a', function() {
  $("#thumbs").html(temp);
});
```

Comment: it is worked perfect you are the only one know what i want , thank you very much